# What does $\left|B\right|$ mean?

Tags: matrices, notation, definition

**Question:** Suppose that $B$ is a matrix. What does (in general) $\left|B\right|$ mean?

**Example:** Let $B_{GS}$ be the iteration matrix for the [Gauss-Seidel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Seidel_method) iterative method. I am given the following lemma:

Assume that $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and assume $B_{GS}$ to be the Gauss-Seidel iteration matrix. Then $$\left|B_{GS}\right| \leq (I-L)^{-1}\left|U\right|.$$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Determinant. It's a bit more common when writing out matrices in full: $\left|\begin{matrix} 1 & 2 \\3  & 4\end{matrix}
\right| = \det \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 4\end{pmatrix}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inequality in the statement of the theorem eliminates the possibility that the notation $|A|$ refers to the determinant of $A$. It simply makes no sense to compare a real number to a matrix.

Given the context, it is likely that $|A|$ refers to the matrix $B = [b_{ij}]$ where $b_{ij} = |a_{ij}|$. The inequality should be interpreted in the componentwise sense, i.e. if $B$ and $C$ are matrices of the same size, then $B \leq C$ is the statement that $b_{ij} \leq c_{ij}$ for all values of $i$ and $j$.

I do not immediately recognize the validity of the theorem. The choice of $A=I$ leads to $L=I$ which renders the right hand side meaningless. It is clear that some significant restrictions are missing.

Answer (score 2):

In general $|B|$ means $\det(B)$

**Not sure what the following lemma means, but the notation is correct**

So it's saying $\det(B_{GS})\leq (I-L)^{-1}\det(U)$, which makes sense since they are all just matrices.

It is possible for $|B|\lt 0$, this is **not** an absolute value symbol in this context

Comment: how does that make sense? the RHS is a matrix and the LHS is a number?

Comment: Not sure of this lemma, but I'm certain of the notation, I'll remove that line, thanks

Comment: Perhaps $|B_{GS}|$ is a matrix itself, I'm not sure what this lemma means

Comment: In this context, I would think that the vertical lines mean operator norm instead of determinant, and that they should be around both factors of the RHS. Not sure tough

Comment: What is norm of a matrix? Unless they express the matrix as a vector?

Comment: a matrix is a linear map, which as a so called operator norm (supremum on unit ball) see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_norm

Comment: @KSplitX As Carl Christian pointed out; it doesn't really make sense that $\left|B_{GS}\right| = \det(B)$ right? That would mean that we're comparing a matrix with a real number,